# Javascript Parameters necessary or not?

Tags: javascript

Why do we exactly need parameters in js functions? Can we not use the variables defined globally. For e.g. Should I define two variables globally to calculate the area of a rectangle, or use parameters as shown here:

```
//This one..
let breadth = 10;
let length = 20;
function rectArea() {
    return length*breadth;
}
console.log(area());
//or..
 function rectArea(length,breadth) {
     return length*breadth;
}
console.log(area(20,10));
```

Comment: This a primarily opinion-based question and should be closed.  IMO, it's always better to use parameters, that way you can reuse your methods, test them, Etc.

Comment: Polluting global scope never helps. If you see in long term, you have 100s of functions with 100s of parameters with 10s of developers, how are you going to make sure that no body has overriden other's variables or rather how would I come to know where variables for functions exist. Also reusing functions would be then reusing functions and their variables etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we not use the variables defined globally.

You *could*, but in all languages Global variables are a bad practice because it's too easy to overwrite them and your code becomes less modular and thus less scalable.

Having each function in control over its own data is a fundamental pattern in almost all modern programming languages, certainly in object-oriented ones.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather pass the parameter and use them. This will help in writing maintainable function reuse and write pure function. Also testing will be easier and relying on global parameter can sometime led to erroneous result as you never know which other function is changing them